# Strange behaviour of media element

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mediaelement

I'm making a media player with basic functions, but it is behaving strangely, when pause play or stop button is clicked following exception occurs 'System.NotSupportedException' Additional information: Cannot control media unless LoadedBehavior or UnloadedBehavior is set to Manual.

Required code and xaml is as follows:

XAML:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="VideoPreview" LoadedBehavior="Manual"  UnloadedBehavior="Stop" Width="auto" Height="250"  MediaOpened="Element_MediaOpened" MediaEnded="Element_MediaEnded" Source="{Binding SelectedItem.SourceUri, ElementName=VideoList}" Margin="5,5,5,5" Stretch="Fill"/>
```

Code behind:

```
void OnMouseDownPlayMedia(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs args)
{         
    VideoPreview.Play();
}

// Pause the media. 
void OnMouseDownPauseMedia(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs args)
{
    VideoPreview.Pause();
}

// Stop the media. 
void OnMouseDownStopMedia(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs args)
{
    VideoPreview.Stop();
}
```

When either of the mouse events is clicked I get the exception.

Comment: I had made a mistake by writing "m" of Manual in lowercase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer *really* is in the error text... *Cannot control media unless `LoadedBehavior` or `UnloadedBehavior` is set to `Manual`*. Therefore, your solution is to set either the `MediaElement.LoadedBehavior` or `MediaElement.UnloadedBehavior` property to a value of `MediaState.Manual`.

From the [`MediaElement.LoadedBehavior` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.loadedbehavior.aspx) page on MSDN:

> LoadedBehavior must be set to Manual in order to interactively control media with the Play, Pause, and Stop methods.

It's amazing what you can find out from MSDN.

Comment: thank you for reply I just had made a mistake by writing "m" of Manual in lowercase.

Comment: 9 years later thIS MICROSOFT STRANGE problem appears all of a sudden in my code, the MediaState.Manual is already in the code and it DOES NOT FIX IT.  Also audio quit playing all together, thank you MICROSOFT for trying to drive me off WPF.